# D3 interactive globe 2d/3d mode jumps on first interaction

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseevent

I've created an example interactive globe with 2d/3d toggle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/wnovo0rb/3/

For both issues, the globe is jumping position the first time the user interacts:

1. 2d zooming jumps the first time
2. 3d zoomed in, panning jumps the first time

Here is the zooming function (where I believe the problem is):

```
function zoomed() {
  var transform = d3.event.transform;
  var r = {
    x: λ(transform.x),
    y: φ(transform.y)
  };
  var k = projection.scale() / 200;
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent.wheelDelta) {
    projection.scale(scale * transform.k);
    if (is3D) {
      transform.x = lastX;
      transform.y = lastY;
    } else {
      projection.translate([origin.x + transform.x - (width / 2), origin.y + transform.y - (height / 2)]);
    }
  } else {
    if (is3D) {
      projection.rotate([(origin.x + r.x) / k, (origin.y + r.y) / k]);
    } else {
      projection.translate([origin.x + transform.x - (width / 2), origin.y + transform.y - (height / 2)]);
    }
  }
  lastX = transform.x;
  lastY = transform.y; svg.selectAll('path.graticule').datum(graticule).attr('d', geoPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 33 and 34 of your fiddle example, simply remove the `/ 2` part from the origin.

Comment: nope doesn't fix it, it stops the initial jumping, but breaks the mouse zoom center?